# how to display a (at least partial) list of keys in Hazelcast using REST

Tags: rest, hazelcast

I know that it is possible to display the value of a key that is part of a Map that was stored in hazelcast using REST.

Using curl this would be done this way:

```
curl -v -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5701/hazelcast/rest/maps/myMap/nameOfKeyInMap
```

But what if I don't know which keys were used ? Following REST principles I skipped the nameOfKeyInMap part of the URL and expected Hazelcast to return a list of keys. But it didn't.

Do you know a way to get at least a part of the keys used ? I use Hazelcast 3.4 and checked the [manual](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/restclient.html) but didn't find a solution

I want to use REST because I need to have people check the maps that don't have much more than a browser on their computers.

Comment: it's been almost 3 years, did you find a solution or a workaround?

Comment: @phoenix7360 Unfortunately neither of them

Comment: I struggle to understand how such a powerful and complex piece of software can have such a poor REST api...

Comment: Still no solution here?